# Symmetries and internal hom in monoidal categories

Tags: monoidal-categories

I need some help in trying to define an object.
Suppose we have a biclosed monoidal category (possibly non-symmetric) and two natural isomorphisms: $B \otimes - \simeq - \otimes B, \ \  C \otimes - \simeq - \otimes C$. Can we put this two isomorphisms together so as to obtain ad an iso $[B,C] \otimes - \simeq - \otimes [B,C]$ ?

Thanks in advance, any hint will be highly appreciated.